# Same Chrome Version, Different Computers dipslay web page differently

Tags: html, css

I have a web site that uses labels and range input sliders.  In Chrome Version 81.0.4044.122 (Official Build) The sliders are where they are supposed to be. On a different machine using the same version of Chrome, they end up in the upper left hand corner of the screen. In both cases, this is on Windows X.  No Chrome themes are being used on any of the two machines. Any idea what would cause different flow on two machines running the same version of the same browser?

thanks!

Brian

```
<style>
.slidecontainer {
  width: 50%; /* Width of the outside container */
  display: inline;
}

/* The slider itself */
.slider {
  width: 30%; /* Full-width */
  height: 25px; /* Specified height */
  display: inline;
}


.sliderLabel {
    width: 10%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.sliderValue {
    width: 10%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.betaAnnotationLabel {
    width:50%;
    display: inline-block;
}

</style>
<div>
    <p>
    <label class = "sliderLabel" for="beta_slider"> beta </label>
    <input class = "slider" id="beta_slider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="80" oninput="drawSIR()" onchange="drawSIR()">
    <label id='beta_value' >0.8</label>
    <label id='beta_annotation'></label>
    <br/>
    <label class = "sliderLabel" for='gamma_slider'> gamma </label>
    <input class = "slider" id="gamma_slider"  type="range" min="0" max="100" value="14" oninput="drawSIR()" onchange="drawSIR()" >
    <label id='gamma_value'>0.07</label>
    <label id='gamma_annotation'></label>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Brian, where are they supposed to be positioned? Centred?

Comment: Hey Diego-  No- It's not meant to be centered It's mean to be above a Google Chart and control parameters for the chart. It's exactly where it's supposed to be everywhere I've tested it.  A coworker, though, has it in the extreme upper left corner of his browser, not above the chart.  When I try it with the same brower (chrome) and os (Windows 10) it displays exactly correctly. I can't reproduce what my co-worker is seeing.

Comment: If you want to see it live, go to https://faceofscience.org/covid19/#modelling